# Using R with Google Analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics

I found a great project called r-google-analytics that I'd like to use so I can manipulate GA dat in R at this website http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/.

I run this portion of the code:

```
library(RCurl)

library(XML)

# 1. Create a new Google Analytics API object 
ga <- RGoogleAnalytics()  
# 2. Authorize the object with your Google Analytics Account Credentials
ga$SetCredentials("INSERT_USER_NAME", "INSERT_PASSWORD")
```

And I get this error message:

```
Error in postForm("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", Email = username,  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing the error?

Thanks!

Kim

Answer (score 4):

see http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html for a thorough explanation and particularly (depending on your preference for security):

If you don't have a certificate from an appropriate signing agent, you can suppress verifying the certificate with the ssl.verifypeer option:

x = getURLContent("https://www.google.com", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and this helped me out:

> Use the alternative internet2.dll by 
>   starting R with the flag --internet2
>   (see How do I install R for Windows?)
>   or calling setInternet2(TRUE). These
>   cause R to use the Internet Explorer
>   internals, which may already be
>   configured for use with proxies. Note
>   that this does not work with proxies
>   that need authentication.

While I was researching the issue, I also discovered that other users reported this issue **when they had non-alphanumeric characters** (i.e. not A-Za-z0-9) in their password.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I only have alphanumeric characters in my password, but thats a good start.

Answer (score 2):

As a good practice some reference to both the R sessionInfo() and the OS (uname -a in unix-like systems) could be of some use!

Some basic Googling could also guide you in finding a solution, see for example:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/openssl-ssl-error-code-14090086-verify-the-ca-cert-is-ok-certificate-verify-failed-703523/

HIH!

Comment: Hi Paolo.  I am completely new to CURL and never use it directly myself.  I read the first link and it seems to make sense to me.  My question is this.  How can I "upgrade" my curl so that it works for R, and subsequently, this package?

Comment: @Btibert3 No easy answer. It depends on which OS you are using.In Unix-like OS (such as Linux and Mac OS X) usually everything works out of the box (at least for recent releases). As a starting point you can use the [curl] tag on StackOverflow, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcurl%5D+install  - Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shortcut, just copy, change pathway and paste:

```
source("C:\\Users\\cloudstat\\Desktop\\Google analytics Plus\\RGoogleAnalytics.R")
source("C:\\Users\\cloudstat\\Desktop\\Google analytics Plus\\QueryBuilder.R")

install.packages("C:\\Users\\cloudstat\\Desktop\\Google analytics Plus\\RGoogleAnalytics_1.1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")

library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(RGoogleAnalytics)

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
curl <- getCurlHandle()
options(RCurlOptions = list(capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
curlSetOpt(.opts = list(proxy = "proxyserver:port"), curl = curl)

ga <- RGoogleAnalytics()
ga$SetCredentials("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to changes in Google API system, this is temporary not available to use. I have written a blog on  "[How to extract the Google aanalytics data in R](http://www.tatvic.com/blog/ga-data-extraction-in-r?utm_source=signature&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=vignesh)" with developed R script.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this . Enter the Client Id and Server from the Google Console API manager.

```
install.packages("RGoogleAnalytics")
install.packages("googleAuthR")
library(RGoogleAnalytics)

client.id <-"################.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.secret <-"##############_TknUI"
token<-Auth(client.id,client.secret)
```